# WPF Controls like a favorites bar

Tags: wpf, visual-studio

I'm trying to figure out what kind of control the favorites bar is in IE/Firefox, etc. Basically something that you can visually store bookmarks on, move around, delete easily.

I've tried doing something with a ToolBar, and while I can add buttons and make them work like I want, deleting and rearranging them is problematic. I also tried listviews, but getting them to display correctly is proving difficult. Maybe something like large icon view, without the icons.

I'm just looking for something where people can bookmark Navigation Pages to go back to one they were looking at before.

Edit:
I guess I don't really even care about the rearranging all that much. I'm just trying to figure out how to

1. Add them progmatically
2. Make them clickable, with a click event
3. Delete them when I don't want them any more

I've tried this as a test:

```
    <ListView Grid.Row="1" Name="ListView1">
        <WrapPanel>
            <WrapPanel.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Name="mnuDelete" Header="Delete" />
                </ContextMenu>
            </WrapPanel.ContextMenu>
            <Button Name="AddSite">+</Button>
            <ListViewItem Content="Test 1" />
            <ListViewItem Content="Test 2" />
        </WrapPanel>
    </ListView>
```

But I can't even select either of the listviewitems, let alone click on them. If I right click on one, it doesn't tell me which one I've clicked on in the context menu event handler.
It's frustrating because in WinForms I would have had this done already. I can't wait until I've picked up enough so that WPF just starts clicking. I feel like I'm moving from VB6 to VB.Net all over again, but more so.

Comment: It's just a ListBox with drag-n-drop support. And this rearranging is the most difficult part. I remember some articles, but it isn't easy to take them and apply to your own list box.

Comment: I haven't really tried listboxes in WPF yet. Would one work better than a listview? It seems like this would be similar to a listview with icon view selected.

Comment: actually ListView and ListBox are almost the same in WPF. ListView inherits from ListBox, it only adds a View property that you can use to assign a predefined layout (like a GridView)

Comment: I'm really going to have to study these things. maybe get a book or two... It's cooling having so much customability, but I miss the built in features that I have to do for myself now, or at least learn the new names of/thought patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think I got it working the way I want, minus the reordering.
I can live with that for now.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Tracks" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="20" />
            <RowDefinition Height="26" />
            <RowDefinition Height="265*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Menu Name="Menu1" />
        <Frame Grid.Row="2" Name="Frame1" Source="PageSearchResults.xaml" />
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1">
        <Button Name="AddSite">+</Button>
        <ListView Name="ListView1" MouseDoubleClick="ListViewItem_MouseDoubleClick">
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ListView.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Name="mnuDelete" Header="Delete" />
                </ContextMenu>
            </ListView.ContextMenu>
        </ListView>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

VB:

```
Class MainWindow 
    Dim bookmarks As New ArrayList

    Private Sub mnuDelete_click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles mnuDelete.Click
        If Not ListView1.SelectedValue Is Nothing Then
            bookmarks.RemoveAt(ListView1.SelectedValue)
        End If
        ListView1.Items.RemoveAt(ListView1.SelectedIndex)
    End Sub

    Private Sub AddSite_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles AddSite.Click
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        Dim itmX As Integer
        Dim itm As New ListViewItem
        i = bookmarks.Add(Frame1.Content)
        itmX = ListView1.Items.Add(New DictionaryEntry(i, Frame1.Content.title))
        ListView1.DisplayMemberPath = "Value"
        ListView1.SelectedValuePath = "Key"
    End Sub

    Private Sub ListViewItem_MouseDoubleClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs)
        If Not ListView1.SelectedValue Is Nothing Then
            Frame1.Content = bookmarks(ListView1.SelectedValue)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

And that gives adding and deleting bookmarks in WPF window with a frame and a listview as a bookmark bar. I'm open to suggestions to improve it or better ways to do it.

Comment: I would add the ItemTemplate implementation (a text with a picture, and a url in the tooltip). Also it would be better to use the ObservableCollection class, you can bind it to the ListView and add or remove items from the collection, not from the actual control. The ListView.*Path properties can be set one time in the xaml. And a selected item not always equals a clicked item, try to call sender.Parent.PlacementTarget.DataContext with correct casts. After some time you can notice that almost everything can be done without events and code-behind.

Comment: Wow, I have a bunch to learn. Observable collections look interesting, but setting up the classes to hold the data seems like a lot of work, esp if you have a lot of list boxes that you need to keep track of. Add to that the fact that most list boxes are only used on one page, and it seems like classes (mostly good for reusability) are an interesting choice. So either generic classes that can actually be reused, but not good for much otherwise, or a lot of good classes... More reading ahead.

Comment: You think right about reusable separate classes. This approach is called MVVM (Model-View-ViewModel) and now it is almost the standard of building WPF applications.